# unwind some merges in working copy

Tags: git, merge

I just merged 50+ commits into my current branch and resolved several conflicts.  Then I realized that I don't really want some of the commits.  Fortunately, those ones were unrelated to the conflicts.  I haven't checked in the merged code yet.

How do I unwind the unwanted commits?

I could just start over and redo the merge & conflicts.
But I thought there might be a way to unwind them as if they were not merged before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to create additional commits on top of your merge commit with [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

First, do a commit to record your hard work (even though its content isn't fully what you want).
Then:

```
git revert -n commit_not_wanted_1 commit_not_wanted_2 ...
```

That way, you reverse the effect of those commits in a new one whose content effectively cancel said unwanted commits.

I would use the `-n` option:

> This flag applies the changes necessary to revert the named commits to your working tree and the index, but does not make the commits.
>
> This is useful when reverting more than one commits' effect to your index in a row.